# C++ concepts and boost geometry

Tags: templates, c++-concepts, boost-geometry

I have an operator template, that calls a boost geometry function template for types `T1`, `T2`. If this function template cannot be instantiated for types `T1`, `T2`, then I want the compiler to choose a fallback operator template. How do I manage this using c++20 concepts?

The following does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

/*
 * Concept requiring that the template function "boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>"
 * can be instantiated for types T1, T2
 */
template<typename T1, typename T2>
concept WithinCanBeInstantiated = requires(const T1& t1, const T2& t2)
{
  boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
};

struct Within {
    /*
     * Operator template that should be used, if "boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>"
     * can be instantiated for types T1, T2
     */
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    requires WithinCanBeInstantiated<T1, T2>
    bool operator()(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) const
    {
      return boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
    }
    
    /*
     * Operator template that should be used, if "boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>"
     * cannot be instantiated for types T1, T2
     */
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    requires (not WithinCanBeInstantiated<T1, T2>)
    bool operator()(const T1& t1, const T2& t2) const
    {
      return false;
    }

};

int main() {
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_type;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_type> polygon_type;

    polygon_type poly;
    boost::geometry::read_wkt(
        "POLYGON((2 1.3,2.4 1.7,2.8 1.8,3.4 1.2,3.7 1.6,3.4 2,4.1 3,5.3 2.6,5.4 1.2,4.9 0.8,2.9 0.7,2 1.3)"
            "(4.0 2.0, 4.2 1.4, 4.8 1.9, 4.4 2.2, 4.0 2.0))", poly);

    point_type p(4, 1);

    Within within;
    std::cout << "within exists: " << within(p, poly) << " no within: " << within(poly, p);
}
```

Tried to compile with

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
```

What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot intercept a static_assert or any other hard error and turn it into a nice substitution failure.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The problem is, I don't know the difference between a static_assert or other hard error and a substitution failure. In the end, the compiler refuses to instantiate boost::geometry::within<T1, T2>, and I was expecting, that's exactly, what is checked with the concept requirement.....

Comment: "I don't know the difference between a static_assert or other hard error and a substitution failure." You cannot effectively use concepts without having a good understanding of that distinction. Roughly speaking, substitution failures occur at *parameter substitution time* and are localized in *template heads*. Hard errors occur at *template instantiation time* and are localized in *template bodies*.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Okay, thanks for your explanation. c++-concepts are a new concept to me, and I also didn't attend the compiler lecture at university, so it would be of great help, if someone with more insight could tell me, if that, what I am trying to achieve, is possible with c++ concepts (and how) or not.

Comment: They usually don't teach this stuff in universities. It is very specific to C++ and to C++>=20 at that. No, you cannot achieve what you want. Concept requirements are not specified in terms of which templates can or cannot be instantiated, but rather in terms of which templates can or cannot be *found*. For example, if you have a `template <typename T> T min(T, T)` and you are trying to use `min(42, "bye")`, an appropriate template cannot be *found*. It is a *substitution failure*. You cannot substitute types of both `42` and `"bye"` into the same `T`. The body of `min` is irrelevant.

Comment: OTOH if you have `struct Foo{}; min(Foo{}, Foo{});` the compiler will find the above `min` for which parameter substitution works, attempt to instantiate it, and fail because `Foo` object cannot be compared. The error is in the body. This is a hard failure.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Then c++-20 concepts doesn't work as I expected. Learned something again, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, it's a mistake many people make when learning this concept. The way it works seems counter-intuitive at first. But it actually cannot work the other way.